# How to permit array of array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have one request where one of the fields is array of array.
parameters

```
{ 
  "product" => { 
    "pitch_points"=>{
      "adwords"=>{
        "search"=>{
          "short"=>["qwe"], 
          "long"=>[["asdadas", "dasdasdas"]] 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

How can we permit this long key?

I have done like this

```
params.require(:product).permit( 
  pitch_points: [
    adwords: [ 
      search: [ 
        short: [], 
        long: [] 
      ] 
    ] 
  ]
)
```

.my output is

```
{
  "pitch_points"=>{
    "adwords"=>{
      "search"=>{
        "short"=>["qwe"], 
        "long"=>[]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but output is empty long.

Comment: doesnt "long"=>[][] work?

Comment: `params[:product].permit!` to permit all the params.

Comment: @PardeepSaini permit is introduce security reason. so direct permit! is not acceptable and also I would like to suggest that Please try to avoid this permit! option directly.

Comment: @Boltz0r I have one requirement where I have to save object when request in 'application/json' we can send params in array of array format.

Answer (score 1):

You can't explicitly permit it.

If you check the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) it notes that strong parameters can be either a permitted scalar type or an array of permitted scalar types. Since an array is not a permitted scalar type you cannot whitelist an array nested within another array.